# Converting DateTime Stamp to String format using Derived column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm very new to SSIS and I'm trying to convert a DateTime Stamp to String format using a Derived column in ssis, i.e dd/mm/yy 00:00:00 to ddmmyy 000000. But I'm totally confused about how to do this even after going through MSDN library. Please help me, even though it's an easy question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your case.

I gave my dft source query as this.

```
Select  Convert(varchar(100),'23/03/90 00:01:00',100) yourDay
```

In the dft source, I made sure that teh datatype is Datetime

[image]

[image]

Your can use the following expression in derived column.

```
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("Day",yourDay),2) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("Month",yourDay),2) + 
RIGHT((DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("Year",yourDay),2) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("Hh",yourDay),2) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mi",yourDay),2) + 
RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("s",yourDay),2)
```

---

**Edited:** 
Derived column content.

See where is the expression given.

[image]

Comment: continue working as explained..create derived column task, with the above expression

Comment: I think you are confused, What I told is the source setting. From the source you create a derived column transformation and create a derived column with the above expression. The output will be as per your requirement.

Comment: Image 1, is the 'Show Advanced editor..' of OLEDB source